# Enabling Short Tags in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to upload a legacy app to an EB instance, but it keeps on failing. And I figured that PHP needs to support short tags in order for the application to run. With this, I thoroughly searched for  any solution in the EB docs, and can't seem to find anything. Can someone point to a good direction?

I have been searching here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by short tags?

Comment: short_open_tags directive for apache

Answer (score 0):

Referencing: https://serverfault.com/a/546784

> The cleanest way I found is to use a [.ebextensions config file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-files) in my
>   project archive:
>
> Sample .ebextensions/project.config file:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 64M
      post_max_size = 64M
```

> When the application version is deployed, this will write a custom config file in the php.d directory, that will
>   override any php.ini setting.